# Access to the form values via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I am trying to obtain the form values from JavaScript. The HTML code of the form is:

```
<form action="./ExampleServlet" method="POST" id="myform">
    <label>Username</label> 
    <input type="text" name="user"><br>

    <label>Password</label> 
    <input type="password" name="pswd" id="launchX"><br>

    <div class="action_btns">
        <div class="one_half last" id="loginButton">
            <a onclick="document.getElementById('myform').submit();" class="btn btn_red">Login</a>
        </div>
        <div class="one_half last" id="bottonBack">
            <a href="#closeButton" class="btn btn_red">Back</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

```js
$(function(){
    $("#launchX").keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            alert('You pressed enter!');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "./ExampleServlet",
                //data: {formValues: "formValues="+JSON.stringify($("#myform"))}
                data : { 
                    formValues: "formValues=" + $("#myform")[0].action
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

How can I send to my servlet only the values for the form (user and pswd parameters)?

Note 1: I commented `//data: {formValues: "formValues="+JSON.stringify($("#myform"))}` to toggle in-out some server-side console output tests.

Note 2: in this case the form `$("#myform")[0].action` returns correctly printing the url of the servlet. I tried also `$("#myform")[0].method` and it returns `post` as a string as expected.

Note 3: the form `JSON.stringify($("#myform"))` returns the entire "form object" and it prints all the form fields, but I can't find the field "user" and "pswd", i.e. the parameters I need.

I suppose to use `$('#myform').serialize()` but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noted, you should use the `serialize()` method on the form. Here's how:

```
$("#launchX").keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "./ExampleServlet",
            data: $('#myform').serialize()
        });
    }
});
```

Note that you could make this more dynamic by traversing the DOM to find the form related to the input that raised the event and setting all properties of the AJAX request from that form:

```
$("#launchX").keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        var $form = $(this).closest('form');
        $.ajax({
            type: $form.prop('method'),
            url: $form.prop('action'),
            data: $form.serialize()
        });
    }
});
```

Either of the above will work for you.